# How I prevent deadlock occurrence in my application?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I am developing an LMS application in PHP framework(Codeigniter 2.1.0). I am using MySQL database.
All the tables in the database have innodb engine. I also created indexes on each tables.
Now I am doing load testing using Jmeter version 2.9 locally for 200 users concurrently. During the load testing, in a specific page action I got **Deadlock Found** error. I changed my original query to the new one but again same error is occurring.

I have written save_interactions function which takes four parameters interaction array,module_id,course_id,user_id & is been called so many times by the AJAX script.
The following script inserts the record if the specific interaction_id is not present in that table otherwise the update query will get fire.

```
public function save_interactions($interaction_array,$modid,$cid,$uid)
{
    foreach($interaction_array as $key=>$interact_value)
    {
        $select_query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `scorm_interactions` WHERE `mod_id`='".$modid."' AND `course_id`='".$cid."' AND `user_id`='".$uid."' AND `interaction_id`='".$interact_value[0]."'");
        $fetchRow = $select_query->row_array();

        if($fetchRow['total']==1)
        {
            $update_data = array(
                        "interaction_type"=>$interact_value[1],
                        "time"=>$interact_value[2],
                        "weighting"=>$interact_value[3],
                        "correct_response"=>$interact_value[4],
                        "learner_response"=>$interact_value[5],
                        "result"=>$interact_value[6],
                        "latency"=>$interact_value[7],
                        "objectives"=>$interact_value[8],
                        "description"=>$interact_value[9]
            );
            $this->db->where('mod_id', $modid);
            $this->db->where('course_id', $cid);
            $this->db->where('user_id', $uid);
            $this->db->where('interaction_id', $interact_value[0]);
            $this->db->update('scorm_interactions', $update_data);
        }else
        {
            $insert_data = array(
                        "user_id"=>$uid,
                        "course_id"=>$cid,
                        "mod_id"=>$modid,
                        "interaction_id"=>$interact_value[0],
                        "interaction_type"=>$interact_value[1],
                        "time"=>$interact_value[2],
                        "weighting"=>$interact_value[3],
                        "correct_response"=>$interact_value[4],
                        "learner_response"=>$interact_value[5],
                        "result"=>$interact_value[6],
                        "latency"=>$interact_value[7],
                        "objectives"=>$interact_value[8],
                        "description"=>$interact_value[9]
            );
            $this->db->insert('scorm_interactions', $insert_data);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this type of error:

Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

```
UPDATE `scorm_interactions` SET
    `interaction_type` = 'choice',
    `time` = '10:45:31',
    `weighting` = '1',
    `correct_response` = 'Knees*',
    `learner_response` = 'Knees*',
    `result` = 'correct',
    `latency` = '0000:00:02.11',
    `objectives` = 'Question2_1',
    `description` = ''
WHERE
    `mod_id` =  '4' AND
    `course_id` =  '5' AND
    `user_id` =  '185' AND
    `interaction_id` =  'Question2_1'
;

Filename: application/models/user/scorm1_2_model.php Line Number: 234
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to avoid **Deadlock**?

Comment: Not sure if this may help, but you may want to try the "create an auxiliary seemaphore table" suggestion at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Answer (score 5):

## DISCLAIMER : Not a Codeigniter Person, Just a MySQL DBA

Looking at the flow of control in the PHP. It says to me:

- Check the following `mod_id`,`course_id`,`user_id`,`interaction_id`
- If not found, `INSERT` the new row
- If found, `UPDATE` all the other columns

There are three(3) mechanisms provided for INSERT and UPDATE scenarios

## MECHANISM #1 : [REPLACE INTO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

```
REPLACE INTO `scorm_interactions` SET
    `mod_id` =  '4',
    `course_id` =  '5',
    `user_id` =  '185',
    `interaction_id` =  'Question2_1',
    `interaction_type` = 'choice',
    `time` = '10:45:31',
    `weighting` = '1',
    `correct_response` = 'Knees*',
    `learner_response` = 'Knees*',
    `result` = 'correct',
    `latency` = '0000:00:02.11',
    `objectives` = 'Question2_1',
    `description` = ''
;
```

or

```
REPLACE INTO `scorm_interactions`
(`mod_id`,`course_id`,`user_id`,`interaction_id`,
`interaction_type`,`time`,`weighting`,`correct_response`,
`learner_response`,`result`,`latency`,`objectives`,`description`) VALUES
('4','5','185','Question2_1','choice','10:45:31','1','Knees*',
'Knees*','correct','0000:00:02.11','Question2_1','');
```

This mechanically performs DELETE and INSERT on `mod_id`, `course_id` , `user_id`, `interaction_id`

## MECHANISM #2 : [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO `scorm_interactions`
(`mod_id`,`course_id`,`user_id`,`interaction_id`,
`interaction_type`,`time`,`weighting`,`correct_response`,
`learner_response`,`result`,`latency`,`objectives`,`description`) VALUES
('4','5','185','Question2_1',
'choice','10:45:31','1','Knees*',
'Knees*','correct','0000:00:02.11','Question2_1','')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `interaction_type` = 'choice',
    `time` = '10:45:31',
    `weighting` = '1',
    `correct_response` = 'Knees*',
    `learner_response` = 'Knees*',
    `result` = 'correct',
    `latency` = '0000:00:02.11',
    `objectives` = 'Question2_1',
    `description` = ''
;
```

## MECHANISM #3 : [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Did you know you can perform an exclusive lock on rows you intend to update with precision?

According the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html), you can run a `SELECT` query on the very row and issue a row lock along the way. For example:

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

This will lock the entire table and allow an UPDATE of the counter_field column.

In your case, simply run the two queries back-to-back

```
SELECT * FROM `scorm_interactions` 
WHERE `mod_id` =  '4',
AND `course_id` =  '5',
AND `user_id` =  '185',
AND `interaction_id` =  'Question2_1'
FOR UPDATE ;
UPDATE `scorm_interactions` SET
    `interaction_type` = 'choice',
    `time` = '10:45:31',
    `weighting` = '1',
    `correct_response` = 'Knees*',
    `learner_response` = 'Knees*',
    `result` = 'correct',
    `latency` = '0000:00:02.11',
    `objectives` = 'Question2_1',
    `description` = ''
WHERE `mod_id` =  '4'
AND `course_id` =  '5',
AND `user_id` =  '185',
AND `interaction_id` =  'Question2_1'
;
```

## EPILOGUE

As a safety cushion, try increasing [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) if the traffic is write-heavy. See my StackOverflow post : [**How to debug Lock wait timeout exceeded?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6005564/491757)

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I increased innodb_lock_wait_timeout to 120 sec as you said. I also read your StackOverflow Post: How to debug Lock wait timeout exceeded? I have used mechanism no 3.....i.e. SELECT... FOR UPDATE. But I am getting syntax error. I mentioned a error below.

Comment: A Database Error Occurred.Error Number: 1064.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `scorm_interactions` SET `interaction_type` = 'choice', `time` = '10:45:3' at line 1.

Comment: I updated my answer. I had missed a comma in the SELECT just after mod_id. I also forgot the actual FOR UPDATE clause.